# How to get a list of users on a birthday table in a given month?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to get the list of users (UserId) who celebrate their birthday in the months of February and August

I have already tried these:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
   var Model = db.Users.Where(u => u.Birthday.Value.Month == 02);


public ActionResult Test()
{
    var Model = db.Users.Where(u => u.Birthday.Value.Month == 02).ToList();
```

I expected a list of `UserId` that celebrate birthday in the months of February and August.

Comment: Your current code returns a list of Users. Do a Select method call on the result of the `Where` method call , if you want only the userId. `Select(a=>a.UserId).ToList()`

Comment: I see _== 02_ but where is _== 08_?

Comment: and Don't forget the null check :)

Comment: Thanks TanvirArjel, Shyju and Sami. But still get wrong:

public ActionResult Test()
  {

            var Model = db.Users.Where(u => u.Birthday.Value.Month == 02||u.Birthday.Value.Month == 08).Select(c=>c.UserID).ToList();


i got this: " The list: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]"

Comment: @TanvirArjel, do you know what's wrong?

Comment: @Osvaldo Can you give me remote access please!

Comment: @TanvirArjel i am not with my computer now. We can make it later. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var model = db.Users.Where(u => u.Birthday.Value.Month == 02).Select(c=>c.UserId).ToList();
```

that shoud give you the list with the UsersID ( for february) if you want both months try:

```
    var model = db.Users.Where(u => u.Birthday.Value.Month == 02 || u.Birthday.Value.Month == 08).Select(c=>c.UserId).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you Kim! But still get something wrong:
public ActionResult Test() { var Model = db.Users.Where(u => u.Birthday.Value.Month == 02||u.Birthday.Value.Month == 08).Select(c=>c.UserID).ToList(); 


i got this: " The list: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]"

Comment: I don't know if you didn't include the complete error. But it seams correct to me. the System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] is the type of the list. Its the same as List<int>. try to make a "Model.Count()" to see if you get any results...

Comment: another thing, dont use "Model" as a variable name. I didnt know you were using MVC, Model is a reserved word for that context. Try chaging that. I'll also edit the anwser...

Comment: @Osvaldo please add this as the answer if it helped you... let me know if you got it working...

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
var Model = db.Users.Where(u => u.Birthday.Month == 02 || u.Birthday.Month == 08).ToList();
```